# Weighted linear least squares in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, least-squares

OpenCV's `cvSolve` can solve a linear least-squares problem like this:

```
// model: y = a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3
CvMat *y = cvCreateMat(N, 1, CV_64FC1);
CvMat *X = cvCreateMat(N, 3, CV_64FC1);
CvMat *coeff = cvCreateMat(3, 1, CV_64FC1);

// fill vector y and matrix X
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    cvmSet(y, i, 0, my_y_value(i) );
    cvmSet(X, i, 0, my_x1_value(i) );
    cvmSet(X, i, 1, my_x2_value(i) );
    cvmSet(X, i, 2, 1 );
} 

cvSolve(X, y, coeff, CV_SVD);
// now coeff contains a1, a2, a3
```

However, I would like to apply different weights to my data points. How do I apply the weights?

Answer (score 4):

I found out it's actually not that difficult:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
{
    double w = weight(i);

    cvmSet(y, i, 0, w * my_y_value(i) );
    cvmSet(X, i, 0, w * my_x1_value(i) );
    cvmSet(X, i, 1, w * my_x2_value(i) );
    cvmSet(X, i, 2, w );
}

cvSolve(X, y, coeff, CV_SVD);
```

This fragment simply multiplies both the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the linear equation with weight w. The error term for sample `i` is effectively multiplied by w².

Comment: what is my_y_value, my_x1_value and my_x2_value?

Comment: They're meant to provide the values for your matrix (x1, x2) and left-hand side (y). This is just the most general form, you can rewrite the code and provide the values in whichever way suits you best. Also be sure to look at the OpenCV docs for cvSolve.